# What is the best structured resource for self training?

Tags: training

I have been playing and studying chess for quite some time. I have tons of books but it all seems very haphazard. I was looking for some resource or course where things are lined up as sequence of well structured lessons.

My current USCF rating is 1451 and I am unable to break above 1500.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reading the [Artur Yusupov training course](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/docs/14/artur_yusupovs_awardwinning_training_course/) and I can tell you it's really great! But I don't have so many books.

The series is supposed to be a three years training course (but I think it will take a bit longer to me): Fundamentals (1600-1800 FIDE), Beyond the basics (1800-2000 FIDE) and Mastery (2000-2200). Every year is made of three books: Build Up Your Chess, Boost Your Chess and Chess Evolution.

Every book have several lessons (the first one, 24 lessons), each lesson on one topic (Tactics, Strategy, Positional Play, the Endgame, Calculating Variations, Openings, all of them mixed up), and each lesson ends with 12 short exercises (10' each one at most), and it usually takes to me 1:30 to 2:00 hours to finish each lesson with its exercises.

If you want to take a look, at [Quality Chess webpage](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/docs/14/artur_yusupovs_awardwinning_training_course/) you can find [an excerpt](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/ebooks/Build-up-Your-Chess-1-exceprt.pdf) with the contents and one complete chapter.

Comment: This looks very organized and what was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

GM Daniel King has a [Power Play](https://shop.chessbase.com/en/categories/trainingpowerplay) Training set. It's a Fritztrainer, so very easy to study, better than books. And covers pretty much every aspect of chess. And it's very suitable for your level. If you study it well and complete it, I guess you get +300 USCF in 1-2 year.

I think this is the best resource. I studied it myself as well.

Comment: Thanks Saibot! I have got some videos, but never completed it. Sounds good, will complete it end to end!